# java source file with all possible syntactic constructions

Tags: java

Are there any java source code files with as much as possible of syntactic constructions? Some sort of test files for java compiler. I need that file for testing java source code parser.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Java Compatibility Kit](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/conformance/docs/JCK6bUsersGuide/html/p3.html), as special [Technology Compatibility Kit](http://jcp.org/en/resources/tdk) for the Java standards.